# How to optimize splitting in F# more?

Tags: optimization, f#, simplification

This code is splitting a list in two pieces by a predicate that take a list and return false in the moment of splitting.

```
let split pred ys =
    let rec split' l r = 
        match r with
        | [] -> []
        | x::xs -> if pred (x::l) then x::(split' (x::l) xs) else []
    let res = split' [] ys
    let last = ys |> Seq.skip (Seq.length res) |> Seq.toList
    (res, last)
```

Do someone knows more optimal and simpler ways to do that in F#?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what pred does?  If it requires checking all the elements together and not one by one there is no way to get around O(n^2).

Comment: Are you trying to split the list into two when you get to the first value that returns true from your predicate?

Comment: Yes, you're right O(n^2) is the best for that situation.
About predicate - it is the split point, when predicate returns false. But this is not so important since it's easy to invert predicate's result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can make it tail recursive but then you have to reverse the list.  You wouldn't want to fold it since it can exit out of the recursive loop at any time.  I did a little testing and reversing the list is more than made up for by tail recursion.

```
// val pred : ('a list -> bool)
let split pred xs =
    let rec split' l xs ys = 
        match xs with
        | [] -> [], ys
        | x::xs -> if pred (x::l) then (split' (x::l) xs (x::ys)) else x::xs, ys 
    let last, res = split' [] xs []
    (res |> List.rev, last)
```

A version similar to Brian's that is tail recursive and takes a single value predicate.

```
// val pred : ('a -> bool)
let split pred xs =
    let rec split' xs ys =
        match xs with
        | [] -> [], ys
        | x::xs -> if pred x then (split' xs (x::ys)) else (x::xs), ys
    let last, res = split' xs []
    (res |> List.rev, last)
```

This is different from the library function partition in that it stops taking elements as soon as the predicate returns false kind of like Seq.takeWhile.

```
// library function
let x, y = List.partition (fun x -> x < 5) li
printfn "%A" x  // [1; 3; 2; 4]
printfn "%A" y  // [5; 7; 6; 8]

let x, y = split (fun x -> x < 5) li
printfn "%A" x  // [1; 3]
printfn "%A" y  // [5; 7; 2; 4; 6; 8]
```

Comment: takeWhile have predicate ('a -> bool), but I really need ('a list -> bool) as predicate. And the input order should be preserved as well.

Comment: May be this "Seq.skip" could be skipped and directly to derive right-hand result. I'll think more about.

Comment: I removed Seq.skip from my first code example.  It's similar to the second example but still takes pred : ('a list -> bool)

Comment: Thanks! Your solution is the best!

Answer (score 0):

Not tail-recursive, but:

```
let rec Break pred list =
    match list with
    | [] -> [],[]
    | x::xs when pred x -> 
        let a,b = Break pred xs
        x::a, b
    | x::xs -> [x], xs

let li = [1; 3; 5; 7; 2; 4; 6; 8]
let a, b = Break (fun x -> x < 5) li    
printfn "%A" a  // [1; 3; 5]
printfn "%A" b  // [7; 2; 4; 6; 8]

// Also note this library function
let x, y = List.partition (fun x -> x < 5) li
printfn "%A" x  // [1; 3; 2; 4]
printfn "%A" y  // [5; 7; 6; 8]
```

Comment: Ya, I can't tell if he wants to test the list in chunks with his predicate or one by one.

Comment: Input order has to be preserved and the predicate should take a list as for [1..10] -> [1], [1;2], [1;2;3], etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some foldr way:

```
let split' pred xs = let f (ls,rs,cond) x = if cond (ls@[x]) then (ls@[x],rs,cond) else (ls,rs@[x],(fun _->false))
                     let ls,rs,_ = List.fold f ([],[],pred) xs
                     ls, rs
```